# Displaying collection of records stored in sembast, using riverpod - avoid replacing entire list with loading animation when adding a single item

Tags: flutter, riverpod, sembast

I've been following Andrea Bizzotto's *Flutter Riverpod 2.0: The Ultimate Guide* to connect my data store (Sembast) to my Flutter UI. At the moment (code below), I am using the Streams feature of Sembast in my repository class to return all the records. My understanding is this method streams the entire collection as the items. My controller has a method to add a new item, and as part of that it also updates the state with the new collection.

This is all working, mostly. I can add an item to the db and my display is update with the new collection containing the newly added item. Unfortunately, the entire list is replaced with a `CircularProgressIndicator` during the save/fetch. I get why -- the entire collection is being replaced, and during the load, my stateless component doesn't have the data, so it can't display anything during the `ConnectionState.waiting` stage.

What I'd really like to be able to do is keep the list displayed, and only add (and in the future, delete and edit) the single item. I have not been able to find an example of this sort of interaction. Are there best practices, or at least some code samples demonstrating this type of use case?

Repository:

```dart
@riverpod
ExerciseRepository exerciseRepository(
        ExerciseRepositoryRef ref) =>
    ExerciseRepository(database: ref.watch(databaseProvider));

class ExerciseRepository implements Repository<Exercise> {
  final Database database;
  late final StoreRef<int, Map<String, dynamic>> _store;

  ExerciseRepository({required this.database}) {
    _store = intMapStoreFactory.store('exercise_store');
  }

  @override
  Future delete(int exerciseId) =>
      _store.record(exerciseId).delete(database);

  @override
  Stream<List<Exercise>> getAllEntitiesStream() {
    developer.log('getAllEntitiesStream', name: 'ExerciseRepository');
    return _store.query().onSnapshots(database).map(
          (snapshot) => snapshot
              .map((definition) => Exercise.fromJson(definition.value)
                  .copyWith(id: definition.key))
              .toList(growable: false),
        );
  }

  @override
  Future<int> insert(Exercise exercise) {
    developer.log('insert', name: 'ExerciseRepository');
    return _store.add(database, exercise.toJson());
  }

  @override
  Future update(Exercise exercise) {
    developer.log('update', name: 'ExerciseRepository');
    return _store
        .record(exercise.id)
        .update(database, exercise.toJson());
  }
}

@riverpod
Stream<List<Exercise>> getAllEntitiesStream(
    GetAllEntitiesStreamRef ref) {
  developer.log('getAllEntitiesStream',
      name: 'ExerciseRepository@riverpod');
  return ref.watch(exerciseRepositoryProvider).getAllEntitiesStream();
}

@riverpod
Future<int> insert(InsertRef ref,
    {required Exercise exercise}) {
  return ref
      .watch(exerciseRepositoryProvider)
      .insert(exercise);
}

@riverpod
Future delete(DeleteRef ref, {required int exerciseId}) {
  return ref
      .watch(exerciseRepositoryProvider)
      .delete(exerciseId);
}

@riverpod
Future update(UpdateRef ref, {required Exercise exercise}) {
  return ref
      .watch(exerciseRepositoryProvider)
      .update(exercise);
}
```

Controller (I have a few doubts about my implementation -- I had to experiment a fair bit to get this working, as it deviates from the `FutureOr<void>` in Andrea's sample):

```dart
@riverpod
class ExerciseController extends _$ExerciseController {
  @override
  FutureOr<Stream<List<Exercise>>> build() async {
    final definitionsRepository =
        ref.read(exerciseRepositoryProvider);
    return definitionsRepository.getAllEntitiesStream();
  }

  Future<int> createExercise(
      {required String name, required String exerciseType, required String note, ExerciseSetting? setting}) async {
    final definitionsRepository =
        ref.read(exerciseRepositoryProvider);
    final newExercise = Exercise(name: name, exerciseType: exerciseType, note: note, setting: setting);

    state = const AsyncLoading();
    var id = await definitionsRepository.insert(newExercise);

    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async {
      return definitionsRepository.getAllEntitiesStream();
    });
    return id;
  }

  Future<Stream<List<Exercise>>> getExercises() async {
    final definitionsRepository =
        ref.read(exerciseRepositoryProvider);
    state = const AsyncLoading();
    var definitions = definitionsRepository.getAllEntitiesStream();
    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async => definitions);
    return definitions;
  }
}
```

Provider:

```dart
@riverpod
Database database(DatabaseRef ref) {
  throw Exception('Database not initialized');
}
```

UI:

```dart
      body: Consumer(builder: (_, WidgetRef ref, __) {
        final workoutDefinitionsAsync = ref.watch(exerciseControllerProvider);

        return workoutDefinitionsAsync.when(
            data: (exercises) => StreamBuilder<List<Exercise>>(
                stream: exercises,
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<List<Exercise>> snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    default:
                      var items = snapshot.data!;
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: items.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            var entry = items[index];
                            return Card(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          entry.name,
                                          style: Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .titleMedium,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                  }
                }),
            error: (e, st) => Text(e.toString()),
            loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
      })
```